# Local storage gets all messed up after refresh

Tags: javascript

So, I have a wheel of fortune, the one that u can spin once a day and get a discount for your shop. Someone requested me to make a function that if you're from Europe you have to accept GDPR or something like that before spinning. Everything works fine first time, then when I refresh, it doesn't show up anymore in there, but, if I delete local storage/cookies it works, any ideas? I have the following code =>

```
var europe_loc = ['AD', 'AL', 'AT', 'AX', 'BA', 'BE', 'BG', 'BY', 'CH', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DK', 'EE', 'ES', 'FI', 'FO', 'FR', 'GB', 'GG', 'GI', 'GR', 'HR', 'HU', 'IE', 'IM', 'IS', 'IT', 'JE', 'LI', 'LT', 'LU', 'LV', 'MC', 'MD', 'ME', 'MK', 'MT', 'NL', 'NO', 'PL', 'PT', 'RO', 'RS', 'RU', 'SE', 'SI', 'SJ', 'SK', 'SM', 'UA', 'VA'];
var country_code = bd_get_local('vitals_country_code');
        if(country_code == null) {
            $.getJSON('//freegeoip.net/json/?callback=?', function(data) {
                var country_code = data['country_code'];
                if(country_code.length > 0) bd_store_local('vitals_country_code', country_code);
                var accepted = bd_get_local('cookie_accepted');
                if(accepted == null && europe_loc.indexOf(country_code) >= 0) {
                    $('.bundle-wheel-form').append('<label for="gdprCheck">I have read and accepted the whatever i must type here</label><input type="checkbox" id="gdprCheck" name="europeGdpr">');

                }
            });
        }
```

Code that reads local storage:

```
function bd_store_local(key, value, exp) {
            if(typeof value === 'object') {
                value = JSON.stringify(value);
            } else {
                value = String(value);
            }

            if(lsSupport) {
                localStorage.setItem(key, value);
            } else {
                createCookie(key, value, exp);
            }
        }

if (typeof localStorage !== 'undefined' && typeof localStorage.setItem !== 'undefined') {
            var lsSupport = true;
        } else {
            var lsSupport = false;
        }
```

Comment: You'll need to update the question to include the code that reads/writes localStorage.

Comment: @Archer did it :)

Comment: @JamesThorpe everyone is allowed,but,if you're from EU you must accept some kind of new 'law'

Answer (score 0):

You should set the local storage item only when the user clicks on accept button from the GDPR banner.
SO dont use this `bd_store_local('vitals_country_code', country_code);` only after the user will accept the GDPR.

Comment: Well,he can deny,but i'll still have to store it. Maybe i didn't get your answer,sorry.

Comment: Don't think so:) GDPR is jsut an information about new regulations, the user can just say that he found out about those regulations, is not something you can deny :)